# Redirect to a page does not work if built with variable

Tags: php, if-statement

Why this does not work and gives page isnt redirecting properly error in firefox

```
$page_name = "home.php";

if (true) {
//none
} else {
header("location:http://mysite.com/pages/".$page_name);
die;
};
```

Comment: Are there errors you experience? The obvious one being headers not sent.

Comment: @Johnny not helpful. Chrome does not parse php.

Comment: Try `header("Location:http://mysite.com/pages/".$page_name);` (with upper case "L" in location)

Comment: @Usman, HTTP header names are supposed to be case-insensitive.

Comment: Is PHP supposed to change the response status code from 200 to 30x when it sees user code emit a `Location` header? That would be really strange and ad-hoc. I would look for a way to specify the correct status code explicitly.

Comment: @Henning you are absolutely correct, HTTP headers are case insensitive. If you check the [manual page for the header function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) you will see that PHP will automatically send a 302 if you set a location header and code explictly set the response code. However this should not be relied upon, and 302's don't do everything...

Comment: @Usman Header case is irrelevant. However, the space between the header name and the value IS required according to spec.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, just guessed some error, but was not sure. That's why commented.

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it properly - that method is the lazy redirect:

```
header('HTTP/1.1 302 Found');
header("Location: http://mysite.com/pages/$page_name");
```

Note the spacing and the fact that I have explicitly chosen a response code.

While there is no real reason for what you have done not to work, and also PHP should figure out the fact that you are doing a redirect if you set a `Location:` header and set a 302 code, it's always best to do it properly so you know it should work.

Comment: Same problem if i use capital L and $page_name it gives error if i just type home.php instead it works

Comment: i have function with   header("Location: http://$host$uri/$filename");
that works i just use redirect but this time it does not work maybee its because i grab value from $_POST['link']? do i need to trim it somehow?

Comment: It's not so much the capital, it's the space between `Location:` and the URL. Also make sure you set the status line (first call to `header`).

Comment: I did that too but i like echo actually yap it was same page thats why it did not work same page as currently open, fixed and its works now  thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if (true) {
```

to

```
if (false) {
```

and remove the semicolon at the end of the if statement.

Result:

```
$page_name = "home.php";

if (false) {
//none
} else {
header("location:http://mysite.com/pages/".$page_name);
die;
}
```

If this doesn't work, also change the header calls to follow DaveRandom's advice.